# .htaccess Rewrite Url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a dynamic php site at time variables are stored in url and I don't want them to be seen . e.g original url: http://www.example.com/root_new/news.php?id_new=9 now I want to change this url to http://www.example.com/root_new/news

I initly tried to achieve this with pure PHP but did some research and came across that best way to do achieve this is through .htaccess which is a config file that controls Apatche server anyway....

I am not very good at this but managed to put together a code inside my.htaccess that I belief should do the trick but it does not

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on  



RewriteRule ^news/([^/.]+)/?$ news.php?id_new=$1 [L]
```

of course this file is in my root where the index.php and the rest of the pages are.

could someone suggest a solution to what I am trying to achieve or tell me where I am going wrong with my .htaccess commands.

Comment: `on RewriteRule` should be `RewriteRule`

Comment: sorry thats how i had it pasted the code wrong fined it now

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ....
```

Now, the problem is that if you need a value '9' to pass to id_new, it has to either be in the original SEO format URI, or you have to have a hard coded rewrite that includes it. It isn't going to appear out of thin air.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^news/([^/.]+)/?$ news.php?id_new=$1
```

will work if the incoming URI is `/news/9/` (last / is optional). While easier to type than the dynamic version, the user still has to remember "9". It will also try to send you to "news.php" in any directory, rather than, say, /news.php (make sure that's what you want to do).

You don't need `[L]` because you don't have a `RewriteCond` clause. Note that since you're providing a Query String, any incoming Query String in the original URI will be discarded (unless you add the `[QSA]` flag).

Comment: Thx for your answer, Now of course the 9 does not come form air, it si the id number of a article stored in a database, And as i mentioned i never did this I never worried about making my URL's clear but because i released how important it is for SEO and it is my requirement for the site I am trying to sort this out, Could you perhaps give me a link where I can read about this somewhere where this is explained nicely. thx